# Python tkinter code doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new to programming and have recently started coding in python.
i'm working with a textbook that has codes with sample programs in it. the following code is from that book and is supposed to turn a colored picture into a black and white picture by assigning the colors black or white to every pixel depending on their brightness (the sum of their RGB-values).

```
    from tkinter import *
    def black_white ():
average = 382.5
for x in range (image.width()):
    for y in range (image.height()):
        c = image.get(x, y)
        brightness = int(c[0]) + int(c[1]) + int(c[2])
        if brightness < average:
            image.put("black", (x))
        else:
            image.put("white", (x))

     window = Tk()
    image = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
    button = Button(master=window, command=black_white,
            font=("Arial", 14),
            text="Bearbeiten")

    label = Label(master=window, image=image)
    label.pack()
    button.pack(fill=X)
    window.mainloop()
```

however, the code doesn't work, the error message i get is:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
      File "/Users/(anonymous)/Desktop/programmieren/raspberry_lehrbuch/schwarzweiß.pyw", line 8, in black_white
brightness = int(c[0]) + int(c[1]) + int(c[2])
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

i already did a bit of research but couldn't find anything that made it work. help is very much appreciated :)
oh and i use a macbook pro 2010 with el capitan

Comment: error means you try to convert empty string into integer. Try `int("")` and you get the same error message. Check `c` before you do `brightness = int(c[0]) + int(c[1]) + int(c[2])`

Answer (score 1):

change `(x)` to `(x,y)`, must be position `x, y`

```
from tkinter import *


def black_white():
    average = 382.5
    for x in range(image.width()):
        for y in range(image.height()):
            c = image.get(x, y)
            brightness = int(c[0]) + int(c[1]) + int(c[2])
            if brightness < average:
                image.put("black",  (x, y))
            else:
                image.put("white", (x, y))


window = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
button = Button(master=window, command=black_white,
                font=("Arial", 14),
                text="Bearbeiten")

label = Label(master=window, image=image)
label.pack()
button.pack(fill=X)
window.mainloop()
```

Before clicked:

[image]

After Clicked:

[image]